# tableViewSelectionDidChange: Not Being Called

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

I've worked with NSTableView a couple times before, and I've used this method with no issues, but for some reason in my newest program the `tableViewSelectionDidChange:` delegate method isn't being called when I switch rows. I've created a **very** simple program to try to get to the source of this, but for some reason it still isn't working. I know I'm probably overlooking something small but I've been staring at this for hours and comparing it to my other code where it works and I can't see anything.

AppDelegate.h:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate>

//not sure if the NSTableViewDelegate part is needed, as I've used this before without it

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTableView *tableView;

@end
```

AppDelegate.m:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
}
- (void)tableViewSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)aNotification{
    NSLog(@"Row changed");
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView
{
    return 2;
}

- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex
{
    return nil;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Additionally insert the following lines and see what happens.  Make sure you have set AppDelegate as source and delegate.

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView shouldSelectRow:(NSInteger)rowIndex {
    return YES;
}
```

If that doesn't help, I don't know the cause.

Comment: I made a slight alteration returning the rowIndex.

Answer (score 9):

I also had the problem that the `tableViewSelectionDidChange:` method wasn't called, but only after I've closed and reopened my dialog. It turned out that this "delegate" method does have a notification observer signature for a reason: Apple simply registers your delegate method with NSNotficationCenter. So if you call `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];` like I did in my `windowDidHide` method, you won't get notified about table selection changes any more.

The solution is instead of being lazy and calling `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];`, you need to unregister *only* the notifications that you have explicitly observed before.

Comment: Thanks a million! Was trying to figure out why my Swift code wasn't being called. Turned out I removeObserver(self) was the culprit

Answer (score 2):

You need to set its data source and delegate to AppDelegate by control-clicking on the tableview control and extending the string to AppDelegate's blue icon, if you haven't.

Comment: Just did that and it's recognizing it as the datasource now, but the method still isn't being called.

Comment: 1. Just as the data source or as the data source and delegate?  2. How many NSTableView controls do you have?  Just one?  3. Have you tested it with some rows in the table?

Comment: 1. I've tried it with just the datasource, just the delegate and with both. 2. I just have 1 NSTableView Control. 3. I have two rows in the table right now and am just testing by switching between the two. I've updated my original code with the datasource implementation

Comment: Great! I assume this question is from Cocoa Programming For Mac OS X (4th Edition), Figure 6.10. The connection between the delegate of the table view and the app delegate was mentioned in text, not in that figure.

Answer (score 0):

You need wrap the tableview with a `NSViewController` such as `yourController`, set the `delegate` and `dataSource` of the tableview to `yourController`;

```
self.tableView.delegate = self;
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
```

Of course, you should implement the delegate methods and the datasource methods in `yourController`;

Then:

```
window.contentViewController = yourController;
```

This works for me.